# os walk with changed directory structure

Tags: python

i currently want to improve a python script I wrote once.

In it the structure is roughly like this:

```
def x(args):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
        do_something_that_changes_the_directory_structure()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
        do_someting_with_that_changed_directory()
```

The problem is that i change the directory structure and have to re-read that structure to do something with it. Is it possible to do this with only one for loop? I thougth about while loops but after thinking about it I don't think that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update `dirs` and `files` according to the changes you've made to your folder. For example:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
    with file('{}/test.file'.format(root)) as f:
        f.write('test')

    files.append('test')
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer, unfortunately for me it's not usable for my script, thanks anyway!